# jQuery in iFrame to hide a div

Tags: php, jquery, iframe

I'm building a little upload script. My form has a target to an iFrame and the iFrame locates on the same page as the form.

In the code of the iFrame I upload the files to my server. If the upload is finished i want to run a little jQuery inside the iFrame to hide a div on the parent page (where the form is located).

Strange thing is that the jQuery inside the iFrame doesnt work. If I try a simple 
alert('bla bla bla'); it doesnt show.

Somebody now what i should do?

Thanks in advance!

the code of the iFrame:

```
<?  if(isset($_POST['Q'])) { echo 'form is set';
echo $_POST['Q']; ?>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('#test').show();
});
</script><? } ?><div id="test" style="display:none;">bla bla bla</div>
```

Comment: Start by posting the code you've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using jquery withing iFrame you need to have references to JQuery libraries withing the Iframe itself.